Excel: Inconsistent results of CountIf() on string with tilde
Is this a bug in Excel, or is there a reason for the different results in the table below? If it's a bug, is there a way to predict what strings will be affected by it?
In both match() and CountIf(), I double a tilde to allow the searches to work properly. (This works because tilde is the wildcard escape character.) But I've come across two cases where this doesn't work for CountIf().
In the table below, columns E and F show that substitution of a double tilde allows match() to correctly find the string in the list. But columns G through J show that the same substitution in CountIf() works on rows 4 and 5 and does not work on rows 6 and 7. Instead, on rows 6 and 7, CountIf() works without the substitution and does not work with the substitution.




B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J





String
Formula
Result
Formula
Result
Formula
Result
Formula
Result


4
{FK*BD6Qc)9j~aHa
=MATCH($B4, $B:$B, 0)
#N/A!
=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE($B4, "~", "~~"), $B:$B, 0)
4
=COUNTIFS($B:$B, $B4)
0
=COUNTIFS($B:$B, SUBSTITUTE($B4, "~", "~~"))
1


5
;.D~n[sg9#?$}z3`
=MATCH($B5, $B:$B, 0)
#N/A!
=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE($B5, "~", "~~"), $B:$B, 0)
5
=COUNTIFS($B:$B, $B5)
0
=COUNTIFS($B:$B, SUBSTITUTE($B5, "~", "~~"))
1


6
JFxa7V9."Ap~/Q2g
=MATCH($B6, $B:$B, 0)
#N/A!
=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE($B6, "~", "~~"), $B:$B, 0)
6
=COUNTIFS($B:$B, $B6)
1
=COUNTIFS($B:$B, SUBSTITUTE($B6, "~", "~~"))
0


7
dP4%5>by{Bw#Vt~D
=MATCH($B7, $B:$B, 0)
#N/A!
=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE($B7, "~", "~~"), $B:$B, 0)
7
=COUNTIFS($B:$B, $B7)
1
=COUNTIFS($B:$B, SUBSTITUTE($B7, "~", "~~"))
0



What's going on here? What's the right way to account for the possibility of there being a tilde in the criteria range of CountIf()?

I can't say why escaoing the tilde isn't working, but instead of that, try using CHAR(126) instead of the double tilde in the SUBSTITUTE() function.

@bugdrown - Did you try that, or do you have a good reason to believe it would work? I made the change in column J (whose formula is shown in column I) and it gave me the same results as column H, meaning that the tilde was just replaced with a tilde, which makes sense because char(126) is the tilde.

I did try it on one of the formulas that was yoelding a 0 and it counted  as 1 when I mase the change.

@bugdrown - Please show the formula you say changed the result from 0 to 1 so I can test it here.

@NewSites Actually, you should be "escaping" all the wild card characters as well as the tilde, either with nested SUBSTITUTES or with the REDUCE function. However, the same results occur as you show. I think it is a bug in the criteria argument for COUNTIF, but I've posted a simplified version of this question elsewhere to see if others have an idea.

@NewSites - I verified and it only worked for COUNTIFS(): COUNTIFS($B:$B, SUBSTITUTE($B6, "~", CHAR(126)))

@RonRosenfeld - Link to your question, please?

@bugdrown - Did you test it on all four strings? As I said before, your formula gives me the same as column H, which is 0 on rows 4 and 5 and 1 on rows 6 and 7, which is still wrong. It should be 1 on all four rows. What to you get on all four strings? If you get 1 for all of them, what version of Excel are you using? I'm in Office LTSC Pro Plus 2021.

@NewSites - Office 365. The CHAR() substitution yields 1 only on strings in rows 6 & 7. Yields 0 for strings in rows 4 & 5.

@NewSites Link to my question on Microsoft Answers

@NewSites Please see the Update to my answer.

For reasons which are unclear to me, in defining the criteria argument for  COUNTIF, the tilde ~ must be escaped if and only if there is an actual wild-card character {asterisk, question-mark} present.
I suppose in order to use COUNTIF one could use an IF statement to decide whether to create the escapes or not. Of course, one should escape ALL of the wild-card characters.
=COUNTIF(
    B:B,
    IF(
        OR(ISNUMBER(FIND({"*", "?"}, B4))),
        REDUCE(
            B4,
            {"~", "*", "?"},
            LAMBDA(a, b, SUBSTITUTE(a, b, "~" & b))
        ),
        B4
    )
)

seems to work on all examples.

Update
The common denominator seems to be that with COUNTIF, a tilde is recognized as an escape character if it is followed by a wild-card character, even if there are intervening non-wild card characters. With MATCH, it is always treated as an escape character.
A "Microsoft Agent" has responded to a post of mine on the  Microsoft Answers Community with a comment that this behavior is "by design". To my way of thinking, this design is illogical and non-intuitive. I have submitted Feedback via the Help menu in Excel reporting it and asking that the behavior either be changed or documented.Comments or additional Feedback submissions might do some good.

Nice Solution + the explanation. Sir when you get the feedback from MSFT please do update in the post for future references.

The issue with the search is that the data you have contains wildcards and the functions you are using like COUNTIF and MATCH accept the use of wildcards. You can find the list of functions that support wildcards here.
What you need to do is use a function that does not support wildcards like SUMPRODUCT, the downside is that in only works with a limited range instead of the full column.
Here is an example of how to use the formula.
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$4:$B$7=B4))
Here is an explanation:
$B$4:$B$7=B4 this will match the range with the column and mark the matches as TRUE OR FALSE
--() This will take the matches and turn them into numbers. 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE
SUMPRODUCT will take the entire response for the previous match and sum the values.




B
C
D





String
Formula
Result


4
{FK*BD6Qc)9j~aHa
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$4:$B$7=B4))
1


5
;.D~n[sg9#?$}z3`
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$4:$B$7=B5))
1


6
JFxa7V9."Ap~/Q2g
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$4:$B$7=B6))
1


7
dP4%5>by{Bw#Vt~D
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$4:$B$7=B7))
1



This way you don't need to replace the tildes in the string and still get the matches.

Edit, for the issue with rows 6 and 7:
Rows 6 and 7 do not have other wildcard values like * or ?, so when the string is evaluated, it takes the string values as is.
So this value JFxa7V9."Ap~~/Q2g gets evaluated as that, a string with a double tilde, so it does not match JFxa7V9."Ap~/Q2g which only has a single tilde.
You can test adding a wildcard to the values and see that the matches change:
JFxa7V9."Ap~/Q2g -> 0
JFxa7V9.?"Ap~/Q2g -> 1
JFxa7V9.*"Ap~/Q2g -> 1

dP4%5>by{Bw#Vt~D -> 0
dP4%5>by?{Bw#Vt~D -> 1
dP4%5>by*{Bw#Vt~D -> 1


Actually, tilde is not a wildcard, it's the wildcard escape character, which is the reason that doubling it should work and usually does work. And yes, SumProduct() is an alternative to CountIf(), but it's slow. My question is why the doubling of the tilde is not working on rows 6 and 7. It should work, so there's something strange here, and I'd like to understand it.
